# How would I go about playing a video file with sound in Python and setting the play position?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using ffmpeg to process video files using Python, but I want to be able to open a local video file and use a few sliders to control the timeline in the video, that way I can get the timestamp from where those sliders were moved.

The goal is to get the beginning and end time of the set positions using the sliders, that way I can cut the video at those times using ffmpeg.

Any help would be appreciated...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using python-vlc which works great in Tkinter.

Here's an example VLC has on their website which was a big help.

http://git.videolan.org/?p=vlc/bindings/python.git;a=blob;f=examples/tkvlc.py;h=55314cab09948fc2b7c84f14a76c6d1a7cbba127;hb=HEAD

Here you can find the documentation:

https://wiki.videolan.org/PythonBinding